# Stacked chart with dates on X-axis in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

```
Range   20-04-2020  21-04-2020
0-10    10          14
11-20   23          56
21-30   35          9
```

I have this table for which I want a stacked graph like this (see image): -

[See image  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Tud.png)

As you see I can draw this graph in excel as a 'recommended graph', but cant do it in power bi. Using Stacked bar chart template only shows one stacked column and there is no way I found to plot dates on X-axis.

Look here for more : https://www.edureka.co/community/73585/stacked-chart-with-dates-on-x-axis

Please help.
**Update:** the problem I'm facing with my table: [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaLsE.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fairly simple:

I created a table with 3 columns and 6 rows to present your data.

(Range  | Date | Value)

If you have a different data structure where you have the date as columns, you have to unpivot your data first. However, having this as your base, is not be logic because each new data would create a new column..

Steps to take:

0. Use the stacked column chart.
1. Ensure your date field is of time date (it has the calendar icon in front if it.
   **Be sure you do NOT use the date hierarchy, click on the date in the Axis field and select the date**
2. Your value field should be a number so it can be summed together.
3. As Axis, you use the date
4. As legend you use your range
5. as value, use the values

end result:

[image]

if you also want the number is, set the Data Labels to "On"

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Aldert , How can I transform my table to the table like you have? I have added one more image in question, pls check.

Comment: Also @Aldert Can you update in the answer how your table looks like?

Comment: `If you have a different data structure where you have the date as columns, you have to unpivot your data first. However, having this as your base, is not be logic because each new data would create a new column` :: Unpivoting means creating 'pair-values' things right?, If unpivoting isn't the case with your table then what transformation(s) you have applied? @Aldert

Comment: also  Can you explain why unpivoting isn't good choice?

Comment: unpivot you can do in the m-query editor (Transform data button in bar). I did not need to do any transformation. I created an excel sheet with the 3 columns which I imported).

Comment: Unpivot means creating out of many columns on column with as many rows of data as there is data in your columns. so in your example you have 3 rows and 2 columns of dates. This would become 6 rows with 1 date column.

Comment: The problem is not the unpivoting.  it is more related to your data structure. Imagine, every day you get new data, each day you have to add one new column with a date. to your table..